# Importing Existing Android Project Into Eclipse Renames Project

Tags: android, eclipse, import, project

Every time I import an existing Android Application Project into Eclipse, it renames the project to the name of my launcher activity.

I have tried both of these methods:

```
File -> Import -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace

File -> New -> Android Project From Existing Code
```

In both of these scenarios, I browse to the project folder and select it, which causes it to show in the 'Projects' window as available for importing. However, the project is showing as being titled 'LauncherActivity', or something similar.

**Edit:** It's easy enough to change the project name back to what it was originally, I know how to do this:

```
Right-click on Project -> Refactor -> Rename
```

However, it is annoying to have to do it every time.

**Edit 2:** The .project file contains the correct project name, and yet the problem still occurs.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Have you got the solution??

Comment: @NarendraPal, No, unfortunately not.

Comment: File->New->Android Project From Existing Code will always re-name the project.  I cannot reproduce File->Import->Existing ... renaming the project.  Can you provide the project, for download and identify the version of Eclipse you are using?

Comment: btw... are you using a revision control system, too?

Answer (score 4):

The project name is probably set in the project file.
Try to edit the .project file, and change the name tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Projectname</name>
    <projects>
```

Comment: see my edit. I know how to change it back, its just annoying that it happens every time.

Comment: Since you are creating a new Project and Eclipse doesnt knows the name for that, it picks up the Default Launcher Activty and assigns it as name for that project.

Comment: I mean editing the project file of the project you are importing. It should use that name. If it's not there, it's not strange eclipse picks the first activity as name.

Comment: @timmied I see what you're saying now. Where can I find the .project file?

Comment: The folder you are trying to import with into your Eclipse.  If it had previoulsy given a project name with another eclipse (exported)  It should have the .project file in the root of this directory or zip file.

Answer (score 1):

which version of Eclipse you are using?

I use Eclipse inside the android SDK, no this problem.

Import the project , right click -> Refactor->Rename, project name changed.

Next time I import this project, the name not fallback to original.

You can try the the latest SDK which contains Eclipse [Download Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)